# Three.js - Using PlaneGeometry to generate hills

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm looking for a simple way to generate *no-uniform* hills in Three.js. I've been able to create to a hill effect using particles and positioning them using a sine wave algorithm like (roughly)

```
 x = Math.random() * 1000 
 y = Math.sin( x / freq ) * amp
 z = Math.random() * 1000
```

However, this method seems hacky, and the hills produced are uniform in height. I was thinking of using `PlaneGeometry`, but I'm not sure if this is a good approach. Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're trying to generate a random terrain.
Then, using Math.random is quite prompt to provide cutting edge faces instead of round shaped effect.

The effect you're rather trying to achieve ("natural shaped hills") can be reached faster using a simple [perlin noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) library. 
eg. https://github.com/josephg/noisejs

A full chapter in the book "Three.js Essential" is covering this exact topic.

Comment: Thanks Julien, I just saw your answer— It's actually the direction that I went in.